# Enabling Performance Insights on existing RDS SQL Server DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-performance

I want to enable [Performance Insights](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/performance-insights/) on one of my production db (SQL Server) which has good amount of data. Before doing that, I wanted to know if there a definite downtime/reboot required for it or is it some setting which needs zero downtime to get enabled?
I checked the docs/threads like this one: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=862542 but nothing is for SQL Server database engine.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, you can enable Performance Insights without disruption.

For MySQL/MariaDB, you need to set the **performance_schema** static parameter in the associated parameter group is set to "1", so that Performance Insights can show the database load broken down by detailed wait events. Otherwise it can only show the load broken down by the list state of the MySQL process.[1] A change to a static parameter requires a reboot in order to take effect.[2]

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Enabling.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

Comment: Enabled performance_schema, waited while it's applied to RDS, but still can see no performance insights option when modifying MySQL RDS. Anything else  need to be checked?

Answer (score -2):

There is no downtime, you can update the flag and start monitoring

Comment: Thanks, is there a documentation from Amazon stating officially that there is no downtime. Because for MySQL they say that it requires a reboot of the RDS instance: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=862542

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about the documentation but you can change it and choose apply immediately then the RDS will go into a status (not the exact text) something like "Applying Configuration Changes". But the DB is accessible, it will come back to available status within few minutes.